# Geocode react leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, geocoding, react-leaflet, esri-leaflet-geocoder

Trying to add an address list in ELG.geocode.
error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined; (results)

Original: https://codesandbox.io/s/geocoding-in-react-leaflet-v3x-forked-uilpl?file=/src/MyMap.jsx:632-725

```
    ELG.geocode()
        .text(address)
        .run((err, results, response) => {
            console.log(results.results[0].latlng);
            const { lat, lng } = results.results[0].latlng;
            map.setView([lat, lng], 12);
            L.marker([lat, lng])
                .addTo(map)
                .bindPopup(address)
                .openPopup();
        });

    return null;
```

Comment: There is no error for me. I get the response as expected

Comment: Have You tried on local project or codesandbox? because on codesandbox it works correctly but on my local project doesn't work error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined; (results)

Comment: I will try it now

Comment: works both locally and on codesandbox

Comment: working fine for me, at least on csb.  i recommend checking the network tab of your browser as you load the page, and see that the call / response being made by esri is as you'd expect.  you may find clues there as to why its not working.

Comment: {"error":{"code":499,"message":"Token Required","details":[]}} This is the error after call / response